# Linker error when C++ executable links in Fortran library and main in C++ library

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, fortran, intel

I have a CMake-based project consisting of three targets:

- A static library `FortLib` written in Fortran.
- A static library `LibWithMain` which is written in C++ and contains the definition of `int main()`.
- An executable `App` which links in both of the above libraries.

This is the contents of the CMakeList:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7.2)
project(Mcve LANGUAGES C CXX Fortran)

add_library(FortLib STATIC fort.f90)
target_compile_options(FortLib PRIVATE /names:lowercase /assume:underscore /iface:cref)

add_library(LibWithMain STATIC main.cpp)

add_executable(App app.cpp)
target_link_libraries(App PRIVATE FortLib LibWithMain)
```

(For contents of the source files which can be used to reproduce the issue, see bottom)

My problem is that linking `App` results in the following linker error:

> ```
> libifcoremdd.lib(for_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol MAIN__ referenced in function main
> ```

Note that this reference comes from `libifcoremdd.lib`, an Intel Fortran library which apparently gets implicitly linked in.

This does not happen if the function `main` is defined directly in `App`. This can be shown by exchanging the files `main.cpp` and `app.cpp` in the CMakeList above (so that `main` is defined inside the app). Then everything builds and links successfully. It's the fact that the definition of `main` comes from `LibWithMain` that somehow gets the linker confused.

In my real code, `LibWithMain` is Boost.Test, so moving main out from it is not really an option for me.

The order of the static libraries does not matter: the error is present regardless of which lib follows which on the link line.

My toolchain is Visual Studio 2017 and Intel Fortran 18, my platform is Win64 ("x64" in Visual Studio terminology). No other compilers/platforms need to be supported at this point.

I am a C++ developer and know next to nothing about Fotran or the Intel Fortran ecosystem, so I have no idea what could be causing this or how to solve it. That is therefore my question:

**What is causing the linker error, and how can I fix it?**

---

These simple files, used in the CMakeList above, are enough to reproduce the issue:

*fort.f90*

```
integer function fortfunc
  implicit none
  fortfunc = 42
end function
```

*main.cpp*

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int work();

int main()
{
  std::cout << work() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

*app.cpp*

```cpp
extern "C" int fortfunc_();

int work()
{
  return fortfunc_();
}
```

Comment: Did you tried to change the linking order of the two static libraries, i.e. move the  `LibWithMain` in front of the `FortLib`?

Comment: @vre Not before your comment, but now I have. It doesn't help. I will edit the question to include this bit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how cmake works but I'm guessing that you need to do it the other way round.  It is possible that main is special function in your toolchain and should not exist in a library.

1. build the fortran lib
2. build the c lib without main (app.cpp)
3. build the main using both c lib and fortran lib.

It probably won't moan about missing externals when building the c lib because it is a library and not everything needs to be resolved.

Also, in app.cpp, what you need to remember is that in Fortran, the callee unstacks the arguments but in C, the caller unstacks.

When the callee unstacks, you need __stdcall as part of the declaration.  This used to be extern PASCAL on the older MS compilers.  When a caller unstacks, you can optionally add __cdecl.

Comment: Windows x64 uses a more modern calling convention that doesn't involve caller-pops.  stdcall vs. cdecl is only a possible issue if you're building obsolete 32-bit code.  (The only possible difference is vectorcall vs. fastcall, but IIRC those only differ in how they pass/return `__m128` or `__m256` SIMD vector intrinsic types by value in XMM/YMM registers)

Comment: Guess that is another question for the op - is it 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: Calling conventions etc. are handled correctly by the Fortran options I am passing in. Note that the code links fine if the files `main.cpp` and `app.cpp` are swapped around, so the problem is solely in having `main` come in from a library (the question said that, but I now edited it to make that more explicit). And I'm building 64-bit; added that to the Q too.